# How to share data (Array of custom objects) with today extension using NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, widget, nsuserdefaults, ios-app-extension

Basically what I want to do is populate a UITableView in my today extension with objects stored in an array in my containing app.

I have been reading other answers that have to do with using NSUserDefaults to share data between a containing app and its extension and I found out that you cannot store an array of custom objects in NSUserDefaults. This is the code I've tried so far:

```
let group = "myGroupName"
        let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: group)
        sharedDefaults.setObject(MyArray, forKey: "Subjects")
        sharedDefaults.synchronize()
```

Obviously the above code doesn't work and I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing it, Im still very new to this.

Any help would be much appreciated and if I'm going about this the wrong way please point me in the right direction.

*edit*
 My Array is of type "subject" which is defined in a struct. it is made up of 3 strings (name, time1, time2) and UIColor (col)

```
struct subject{
var name = "un-named"
var time1 = "un-described"
var time2 = "un-described"
var col: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor()}

class SubjectManager: NSObject{
var subjectsMonA = [subject]()
var subjectsTuesA = [subject]()
var subjectsWedA = [subject]()
var subjectsThursA = [subject]()
var subjectsFriA = [subject]()
var subjectsMonB = [subject]()
var subjectsTuesB = [subject]()
var subjectsWedB = [subject]()
var subjectsThursB = [subject]()
var subjectsFriB = [subject]()}
```

what i basically want to do is make the array "subjectsMonA" available to my Today Extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is:

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(array, forKey: "Subjects")
```

and to retrieve it:

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.objectForKey("Subjects")
```

## Update

Type struct is not a subclass of NSObject. Therefore NSUserDefaults won't except it as an object. I would suggest using an NSDictionary for your needs (because I don't know if you can insert a Swift Dictionary).

var subject = NSDictionary()
subject.setObject("un-named", forKey: "name")
...

I apologize if the syntax is wrong I did that off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried what you suggested but i get the error "Type '[(subject)]' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'" on defaults.setObject(array, forKey: "Subjects")... anything I'm missing?

Comment: Hmm. For some reason it thinks either the string "Subjects" or the array isn't an NSObject. How are you defining `array` and you are putting quotes around subjects right (just making sure ;))

Comment: Sorry, should have added more info in my question. I have edited now to show my class "SubjectManager" where my array is defined. Sorry again for only adding it now, hope it helps... I think it doesn't like the fact that my array is a custom object? if I said that correctly :/

Comment: Ah thats the problem. A struct is not a subclass of NSObject. NSUserDefaults can only contain NSObject's such as NSArray's. I will update my answer to show u how I would go about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ah I see... Thanks for the clarification, will try your suggestion :)

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help (maybe throw an upvote this direction ;)) and any time